The ID of the series blocks the operation of the click on the legend
I create a series of graphs by pointing to a custom identifier and clicking on the legend, but it starts throwing an error.
Error message: "AG Charts - update error Error: duplicate definition ids on the same scope are not allowed."
Code:
const series = useMemo(() => Object.entries(data).map(([key, value], index, arr) => {
    const color = interpolateWarm(index / arr.length)

    return ({
      type: 'line',
      xKey: dateField,
      xName: dateName,
      yKey: yField,
      yName,
      data: value,
      legendItemName: key,
      stroke: color,
      marker: {
        fill: color,
      },
      id: key,
    } as AgLineSeriesOptions | AgBarSeriesOptions | AgAreaSeriesOptions)
  }), [data, dateField, dateName, yField, yName])

"dependencies": {
    "@frontend-packages/its-ui-kit": "^4.1.7",
    "@frontend-packages/its-utils": "^4.0.13",
    "ag-charts-community": "^10.0.0",
    "ag-charts-enterprise": "^10.0.0",
    "ag-charts-react": "^10.0.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "usehooks-ts": "^3.1.0"
  },

I am confident that the key is unique. If I remove the ID, the issue stops occurring. However, when I click on the legend for the series ID, I receive an automatically generated ID that does not carry any meaningful information for me. Prior to using version 10 of Ag-charts-React, everything functioned properly. Has anyone else encountered this issue?
I'm trying to create a unique custom identifier for my series, but I'm getting an error.
